# How to minify JavaScript with js error

Tags: magento2

I have some code error due to upgrade in Magento 2 but my goal is to minify js. Till now I know that we can not minify js without correcting error of the code in magento but I want to know some trick some realy awesome trick to minify js even I have some issue in the code.

Answer (score 0):

To merge JavaScript files in Magento 2:

Navigate to **Admin panel > Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer**

Open the JavaScript Settings section and in the Minify JavaScript Files field, select **Yes**.

When complete, click Save Config.

---

If the above solution is not working for you due to some bugs or errors, I would try this [gulp solution](https://gist.github.com/lewisp6/b7c50b4d82ef4d3d5d6dc888e8d1bdba)

Take a look at this: [How to minify/optimise Javascript on Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120405/how-to-minify-optimise-javascript-on-magento-2)

Although, I would strongly recommend fixing the error.

Comment: ok i will think about removing the error but for now i am trying to minify it . if nothing helped me out then will do something like that .

Answer (score 0):

I think all that you need is enable "Enable JavaScript Bundling" and "Minify JavaScript Files" options in system configuration on website level in `System Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer > JavaScript Settings section` and redeploy static content

Comment: sorry i think you dont understand the question  or maybe i didnt explain it correctly . when i minify js in developer mode and after i switch to production mode then js is not minified because there is some error in the code .. i dont want to remove the error i want to minify it only .

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel **Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer** . You will find option to enable js minification, choose it to be **Yes** (This option will be visible only if your developer mode is enabled.)
 .
In your Magento 2 ssh console run the below command to set production mode if it is not set, because minification works only in production mode:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation
```

**Note:** --skip-compilation command is not mandatory, use it if you want skip compilation, i would recommend you to not skip it. Then run the below commands:

```
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: sorry i think you dont understand the question  or maybe i didnt explain it correctly . when i minify js in developer mode and after i switch to production mode then js is not minified because there is some error in the code .. i dont want to remove the error i want to minify it only .

Comment: Please post your error message and file name in the question.

Comment: there is no way to minify js without debuging the error ?

Comment: How can we help until you show us your error.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l09ptk

Comment: Saw the error message, it's not an error message due to minification, it's due to wrong configuration in one of your layout file.

Comment: now all the issues are solved there was some error .. i have corrected it ... but still js is not mionified

Comment: Did you perform the steps that I have mentioned in my answer and the steps mentioned by other answers ?

Comment: yes did everything .... and the issue is when i switch to developer mode and dont deplo static content then site is messed up but js is merged and minified as well . but when i run static content deploy ... site looks ok but no js mergin and minifying .

Comment: Minification won't work in developer mode. You will need to run content deployment again each time you switch mode.

Comment: i did that @sourah

Comment: Seems you didn't get my point in developer mode js minification will not happen even if you have enabled it is what I am saying.

Comment: yes bro :) that i what i am saying ... i did that i have tried production mode also ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83873/discussion-between-samair-ali-and-sourabh-kumar-sharma).