# Tried almost everything to minify js but failed

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

tried almost everything to minify js but failed. there is no error as such in Magento 2.2.6 site is loading no page is down I am on developer mode everything is perfect no issues there but still no js minified. I am fed up need some solution. thanks all type of caches are clean. folder var/ cache, var/view-preprocessed everything . I removed it and clean cache properly. but still, js is not minified. screenshot of the system log file. http://prntscr.com/l0btnh

Comment: Check core_config table and make search with like query, how many js merge files entry you found

Comment: 1 js merge and one css merge . http://prntscr.com/l0jbx0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to minify JavaScript with js error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244226/how-to-minify-javascript-with-js-error)

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Kindly share how to fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

Minification only gets applied in production mode when you actually run the static content deploy command. JS files in developer mode are generated on the fly and are not minified

Comment: i already run static-content command ... i have mentioned in the question i already run all commands . but js is not minified